# PHP Mostrar a hora que clicou no botão e por quem foi clicado

Tags: php

Seguinte, estou criando uma página de funcionários que irá funcionar no esquema de "bater cartão".
Ou seja, sempre que o funcionário chegar, ele clicará no botão dentro do sistema e a intenção era que mostrasse a hora que foi clicado e ficar lá. Depois, quando fosse embora, ele "bateria cartão" novamente e mostraria a hora. No fim do dia, isso seria "zerado" (ou seja, aparecia novamente o botão) e o horário, data e essas coisas iriam para o histórico do funcionário.
PORÉM, não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso, visto que meu conhecimento de programação não é tão avançado.

Não sei como fazer aparecer a data bonitinha na tabela ao lado. Tentei fazer um if, inclui um isset. Enfim, tentei vários métodos mas não faço a menor ideia de como fazer isso. Estou aberta a sugestões, opiniões. Preciso muito fazer isso!

Obrigada!

```
<?php

include './abreConexao.php';

$sqlFunc = "Select * from FUNCIONARIOS";
$rsFunc = mysql_query($sqlFunc) or die (mysql_error());

?>

<table border="1">
    <?php
while($tblFunc = mysql_fetch_array($rsFunc)){

?>

    <tr>

        <td>

            <?=$tblFunc['nome_FUNCIONARIO']?> 

        </td>



        <td align="center">


            <form action="Funcionarios.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="" name="horaEntrada">
            </form>

        </td>

        <td align="center">

            <input type="submit" value="" name="horaSaida">

        </td>

    </tr>

<?php 


    } ?>


    </table>
```

O QUE EU TENTEI FAZER FOI:

```
    <?php 

    $horaEntrada = $_POST['horaEntrada'];


if(isset($_POST['horaEntrada'])){

    $horaEntrada = 1;

}else{

    $horaEntrada = 0;

}

if($horaEntrada == 1){

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $date;

}
```

Comment: Não está dando pra entender onde está a dificuldade. Pode explicar melhor, por favor? Você já tem um banco de dados? Uma funcionalidade como essa exige um banco de dados.

Comment: Sim, tenho o banco de dados, a tabela de funcionários inclusive.

Comment: Minha principal dificuldade é: como fazer eu faço esse esquema de "bater cartão". Se ele não clicar, ficará lá a opção. Quando o determinado funcionário clicar (ou seja, na sua "parte") fazer aparecer a data bonitinha. Eu até consegui fazer aparecer a data, mas não sei como fazer essa ideia de fixar no funcionário que clicou e depois zerar automaticamente e ir para o histórico. Não sei se deu para entender...

Comment: Acho melhor você mostrar os trechos relevantes do código. Talvez seja material pra mais de uma pergunta.

Comment: Vish, tem muita coisa... eu mando apenas o que está na página de funcionários?

Comment: Coloque só o trecho onde você acha que o problema está. Se possível cortando partes desnecessárias

Comment: Bom, coloquei o que eu tinha tentado fazer (meio bobo, mas foi o que veio na minha cabeça para solucionar) e também coloquei a página que eu estou fazendo, mas cortei algumas partes que julguei desnecessário. Minha primeira dúvida é: Faço o php na própria página de funcionários ou crio outra? Se eu criar outra, como retomo para a página de funcionários com as informações alteradas?

Answer (score 0):

Bem tranquilo, assumindo que tu sabe o código, que é simples, vou dar só a lógica.

1- Faz um pequeno form, onde o funcionário entra com a matrícula($matricula) e dá submit através do botão.
2- Em outra página você recebe $matricula por POST e guarda ela no banco assim como o exato momento em que o banco atualizou.

Pequeno exemplo de processamento:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$matricula    = $_POST['matricula'];
$fuso         = mktime(date("H")-3, date("i"), 0);
$hora_ponto   = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $fuso);

$ponto = $conexao->exec("INSERT INTO `funcionarios` ( `matricula` , `hora_ponto`) VALUES ('$matricula', '$hora_ponto')");
$ultimaid = $conexao->lastInsertId();
echo '<center>Registro: '.$hora_ponto;}
header("location: suapagina.php");
?>
```

No final do mês tu consegue facilmente imprimir um relatório de todos os registros inseridos pela matrícula x.

Acredito que com isso tu consegue fazer qualquer tweak necessário pra adaptar pra tua necessidade.

Comment: Desculpa, essa matrícula que vc se refere seria quando ele clicasse no "botão"?

Comment: Isso, faz um input com name="matricula" e da submit no botão, vai requerer que o usuário entre com a matrícula nesse campo.

Comment: Poderia especificar melhor? Desculpa mesmo e agradeço muito pela sua ajuda!

Comment: Você precisa um form tipo esse: https://jsfiddle.net/0wbtbzep/ O usuário insere sua matrícula e clica em Registrar, na página processamento.php você tem o código que passei anteriormente.

Comment: Ah, acho que entendi. Nessa matrícula ele escreve alguma coisa e aí ele sera redirecionado para a página que fará isso, certo? E como eu faria para voltar para a página anterior mostrando a data e a hora do funcionário?

Comment: Editei a resposta com o redirecionamento para outra página ao final do processamento, basta você editar ao seu gosto, agora o retorno de informações como a data e hora que foi realizado o registro é outro caso, pesquise sobre isso.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Eu devo criar uma tabela voltada para esses horários? Uma tabela focada exclusivamente nesse histórico que vai se formar?/

Comment: É o ideal, já que tu vai estar inserindo uma nova linha a cada registro de ponto. A tabela "funcionarios" guardaria então as informações pessoais do funcionário como contatos e endereço, e a "ponto" os registros ponto realizados pelo funcionário. Uma coisa que é ideal de te lembrar é que com esse sistema do usuário inserir sua matrícula, qualquer pessoa pode registrar ponto pra qualquer outra pessoa.

Comment: Sim, eu pensei nessa hipótese. Talvez se inserisse um tipo de senha ou código?

Comment: Não adianta muito, um sistema de sessão(login e senha) não impediria do funcionário passar a senha para outro, mas enfim...

Comment: Ah sim, entendo. De qualquer maneira, a data e a hora ainda é o problema crucial que ainda tenho...